# Building data for POST method on .aspx website in Python

Tags: python, asp.net, post

I'm new to .NET and Python, but I would like to make a program to scrape .aspx site and work with content there (HTML code is enough). I tried some libraries in Python, but all I got is the first page of that site. Seems like I am building wrong POST data, I don't know the right form of the data, what should be included and what not.

http://nastenka.lesy.sk/EZOZV/Publish/ObjednavkyZverejnenie.aspx?YR=2018

```
import requests, urllib, urllib2

r = requests.get("http://nastenka.lesy.sk/EZOZV/Publish/ObjednavkyZverejnenie.aspx?YR=2018")
content = r.text
print content

start_index = content.find('id="__VIEWSTATE"') + 24
sliced_vs = content[start_index:content.find('"',start_index)]

start_index = content.find('id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR"') + 33
sliced_vsg = content[start_index:content.find('"',start_index)]

start_index = content.find('id="__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED"') + 33
sliced_vse = content[start_index:content.find('"',start_index)]

start_index = content.find('id="__EVENTVALIDATION"') + 30
sliced_EV = content[start_index:content.find('"',start_index)]

form_data = {'__EVENTTARGET': 'gvZverejnenie',
      '__EVENTARGUMENT': 'Page$2',
      '__VIEWSTATE': sliced_vs,
      '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR': sliced_vsg,
      '__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED': sliced_vse,
      '__EVENTVALIDATION': sliced_EV}

data_encoded = urllib.urlencode(form_data)


r = requests.post('http://nastenka.lesy.sk/EZOZV/Publish/ObjednavkyZverejnenie.aspx?YR=2018',data=data_encoded)
content = r.text
print content
```

For example, in code I want to get the second page ('Page$2'). I get always the same result, but with different values for ViewState and EventValidation. Where could be the problem, please?

Comment: How many pages do you want? I clicked for a minute or so and it looks like there are at least 230 pages? All of them?

Comment: Are these pages generated with JS? if so, you might have an issue

Comment: @SuperStew pages are generated with JS function in the source code, clicking on the button to next page will call this function with 2 arguments, the first is still the same and the second argument is variable - it holds number of page to be displayed. In that function some form will be filled and submitted, in WireShark I realized that it is via POST method and after this, new HTML code is received and shown in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code requires [`selenium`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html) and [`chromedriver`](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home) to control Google Chrome. Turns out there are 476 pages total (following the url you provided).

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get('http://nastenka.lesy.sk/EZOZV/Publish/ObjednavkyZverejnenie.aspx?YR=2018')

with open('page_1.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(driver.page_source)

page_num = 2
while True:
    try:
        element = driver.find_element_by_link_text(str(page_num))
    except NoSuchElementException:
        elements = driver.find_elements_by_link_text('...')
        if len(elements) == 0:
            break  # less than 11 pages total
        elif len(elements) == 1 and page_num > 12:
            break  # last page
        element = elements[-1]

    element.click()

    with open('page_{}.html'.format(page_num), 'w') as f:
        f.write(driver.page_source)

    page_num += 1

driver.quit()
```

Comment: Dude, that's great! Thank you a lot, this is exactly what I needed, works perfectly.